# MongoDB / SpringData: Remove document from array

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

**What I have**

I have following MongoDB data structure in a `messenger` collection where `participantIds` can send each other `messages`.

```
{
    "_id" : "338b407f-f5e6-4c11-bdae-91067d4794e5",
    "participantIds" : [
        "dc6ab720-19a0-43c9-9896-fed040a9223c",
        "a5732e1b-a9a3-4c86-9520-9fbe42c6ce0c"
    ],
    "messages" : [
        {
            "_id" : "edf08d45-cb2d-4cce-9a0d-c5c67dfbd28f",
            "senderId" : "dc6ab720-19a0-43c9-9896-fed040a9223c",
            // More fields, but left out for clarity !
        }
    ],
}
```

**What I want to achieve**

A user (participant) can delete one particular message by its id if and only if the following conditions are met:

- `messengerId` is found the collection
- `userId` is in `participantIds`
- `messageId` is found in `messages`
- `userId` is equal to `senderId` of that particular message

**What I have tried**

```
mongoOperations.findAndModify<MessengerEntry>(
  // QUERY
  Query.query(Criteria().andOperator(
    Criteria.where("id").isEqualTo(messengerId),
    Criteria.where("participantIds").inValues(senderId))
  ),
  // UPDATE
  Update().filterArray(Criteria().andOperator(
    Criteria.where("elem._id").isEqualTo(messageId)
    Criteria.where("elem.senderId").isEqualTo(senderId)),
  ).unset("messages.$[elem]"),
  // OPTIONS
  FindAndModifyOptions().returnNew(false),
)
```

However, that deletes the particular message but leaves **null** in the array. I assume of the **unset** operation.

How do do correctly remove a document from an array which is a child of some other document?

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution which is using `BasicDBObject` in the pull method

```
mongoOperations.findAndModify<MessengerEntry>(
  // QUERY
  Query.query(Criteria().andOperator(
    Criteria.where("id").isEqualTo(messengerEntryId),
    Criteria.where("participantIds").inValues(senderId))
  ),
  // UPDATE
  Update().pull("messages", BasicDBObject(mapOf(
    "id" to messageId
    "senderId" to senderId))
  ),
  // OPTIONS         
  FindAndModifyOptions().returnNew(false),
)
```